# why I must write the code with four backslashes instead of two?

Tags: javascript, dom, jsdom

I want to write the code like that document.querySelector('#foo\bar'); and it does not work

```
    <div id="foo\bar"></div>
    <div id="foo:bar"></div>

<script>

  document.querySelector('#foo\\\\bar'); // Match the first div
  document.querySelector('#foo\\:bar');  // Match the second div
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript string syntax uses the backslash as an escaping mechanism for special characters. In order to get a string to end up with a *single* backslash, you have to double it.

Then, CSS selector syntax for `querySelector()` *also* uses the backslash character as a special escape sequence start, and so it's the same thing all over again.

Thus parsing the string reduces the backslashes to two, and then interpreting the selector results in `querySelector()` looking for just a single backslash.